# scatter3D with interact is flat

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, mplot3d

I am learning [this tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.07-support-vector-machines.html). In cell [13], it has the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

def plot_3D(elev=30, azim=30, X=X, y=y):
    ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
    ax.scatter3D(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], r, c=y, s=50, cmap='autumn')
    ax.view_init(elev=elev, azim=azim)
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('r')

interact(plot_3D, elev=[-90, 90], azip=(-180, 180),
         X=fixed(X), y=fixed(y));
```

If I change the call to `interact` with direct call to `plot_3D`, I get a nice three-dimensional chart:

[image]

With `interact`, however, I get the following:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Change elev to something which is not 90 degrees.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 30 (which is the default :-) ) worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`elev = 90` means view the plot from the top, so it looks like 2D, just adjust elev will have a 3D plot back. I am using  `elev=(-180, 180)`, rather than `elev=[-90, 90]` so can adjust the elev more freely